# Style slot elements from parent component

Tags: svelte

I would like to have a component apply certain styles to the elements that get passed in the *slot* property.

Example:

**Component.svelte**

```
<style>
  h1 { color: blue }
  p { color: grey }
</style>

<div>
  <slot></slot>
</div>
```

**Then, we would include the element**

```
<script>
  include Component from './component.svelte'
</script>

<Component>
  <h1>My component</h1>
  <p>Lorum Ipsum</p>
</Component>
```

And the result would be:

```css
h1 { color: blue }
p { color: grey }
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>My component</h1>
  <p>Lorum Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`:global`](https://svelte.dev/docs#style) modifier together with a `div` selector to essentially say that any `h1` or `p` tag inside the `div` of this component should be styled.

**Example ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/827a2979f02e4c12ad1f408906c6f5cf?version=3.5.1))**

```html
<!-- Component.svelte -->
<style>
  div :global(h1) { color: blue; }
  div :global(p) { color: grey; }
</style>

<div>
  <slot></slot>
</div>
```

Comment: How to I use child selector inside ``:global()``?